# A correct query to get data from 3 tables and show it as a single element in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose I have 3 tables, `posts`, `post_images`, and `post_links`. 
post.id is a foreign key in both post_images and post_links.

Each post have multiple images.

I need a data which contains post, its images and its links as single element/array item.  If there are 3 posts, I need 3 arrays with each array containing the posts images and links.

My code so far,

```
$data = DB::table('posts')
        ->join('post_images','posts.id' ,'=', 'post_images.post_id')
        ->join('post_links','posts.id' ,'=', 'post_links.post_id')
        ->select('posts.*')
        ->get();
```

with the above query I am getting all the records joined, If i have 3 records with 3 images each, I am getting 9 records, I just need 3 posts with its data as its sub arrays.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not use Eloquent? If you have the proper relationships set up, you can just do `$data = Post::with('images', 'links')->get();` and you'll get exactly the results you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the PostImage model

class PostImage extends Model

```
{
    public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the PostLink model

```
class PostLink extends Model
{
    public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the Post model

```
class Post extends Model
{

    public function links() {
        return $this->hasMany(PostLink::class);
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany(PostImage::class);
    }
}
```

In the view you can reach everything you need.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

    {$post->title} <br>

    @foreach ($post->links as $link)

        {$link->url} <br>

    @endforeach 

    @foreach ($post->images as $image)

        {$image->src} <br>

    @endforeach 

@endforeach
```

And if you want use less queries you could use eager loading to fetch all this data the first time. [Eager Loading Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Should look something like this

```
$posts = Post::with('images','links')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you already have relation in model you just have to use `with` method like

```
$data = PostModel::with('post_images','post_links')->get();
```

make it `dd($data)` and look at this. hope it will work. 
**References:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading